# webrtc build fail in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, webrtc

I built webrtc for my linux (ubuntu 14.04 32 bit) machine. The way I follow to build webrtc is following.

1, download and setup depot_tools and java.

2, fetch webrtc.

3, build/install-build-deps.sh.

4, export GYP_GENERATORS=make.

5, gclient runhooks --force (also try python src/webrtc/build/gyp_webrtc).

6, make.

when make command execute after compile some code following error occur.

```
LINK(host) out/Debug/protoc
        TOUCH webrtc_modules_modules_gyp_audioproc_debug_proto_target_genproto_0.intermediate
        RULE webrtc_modules_modules_gyp_audioproc_debug_proto_target_genproto_0
webrtc_modules_modules_gyp_audioproc_debug_proto_target_genproto_0.intermediate
                Traceback (most recent call last):
                  File "../../tools/protoc_wrapper/protoc_wrapper.py", line 134, in <module>
                    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
                  File "../../tools/protoc_wrapper/protoc_wrapper.py", line 119, in main
                    ret = subprocess.call(protoc_args)
                  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
         return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
              File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
                errread, errwrite)
              File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
                    raise child_exception
                OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
                make: *** [webrtc_modules_modules_gyp_audioproc_debug_proto_target_genproto_0.intermediate]
Error 1
                rm webrtc_modules_modules_gyp_audioproc_debug_proto_target_genproto_0.intermediate.
```

Do you guys have any idea of why? And how to fix this?

Comment: Improved formatting of your question to make it readable. Please add more details like what you have searched till now to resolve this issue

Comment: The trace doesn't reveal what's in `protoc_args` but you could probably easily add that to the code.  It's trying to execute an external program, and failing to find it; ideally, any such dependencies should be documented in the project's `README` or similar.

Comment: The code seems to be looking for your `protocol_buffers` installation.